# How to obtain report of CPU and GPU installation date, uptime hours, overheating errors?

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, cpu, gpu, cpu-usage

#### My Question

**In brief:** *How can I obtain CPU and GPU installation date, usage  history and errors report through windows 10  events logs, or command output or system tools or even through 3rd party softwares?*

I want to find the *above information for my office desktop systems* either from windows events logs or from windows commands or from some pc events logs or registry.

I searched for solution finding partial suggestions, requiring certain commands and installing different tools.

What I was really searching for is a single complete tool or software (like [cpuz](https://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) or [GPUz](https://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/)) which can create a single complete report.

Is there any easiest way to find these detail from amd Ryzen CPU processors  or Nvideia GPU graphic card?

#### My findings

**Q1. About how to retrive The CPU processor and GPU graphics card specifications and their installation dates**

**FINDINGS**

Since Device Manager shows the current devices of the installed CPU hardware, Windows saves information about the system installed processors or graphics cards (or add-in cards) in  device manager .inf files  or registry and errors on it in the event logs or device log and saves also the dates they were installed and uninstalled.

Can we retrieve  date time of  installation of GPU or CPU used  information from  inf files or registry or  can we guess it from date time of remained graphic drivers files , or from the creation time and date of a folder or of a windows info file related to them. Any place where such info is saved in Windows.

I found the way to use the `systeminfo` command to find the date of installation or update of windows installation o windows update

```
systeminfo | findstr /C:"Install Date"
systeminfo | findstr /C:"BIOS Version"
```

**Q2. About how to check the uptime and graphics usage of the CPU processor and GPU graphic cards**

**FINDINGS**

How can I get the idea about the uptime and the number of hours, (days, weeks, years) the processor and GPU was being used?

Can it be derived from uptime of PC computer or HDD power in hours.

Under Windows, [the Microsoft `uptime.exe`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/232243) will do it.

Drag the `uptime.exe` into a command promt windows and adding the `/s` option will give results like this:

```
Since 6/29/2010:

System Availability: 56.4610%
Total Uptime: 16d 7h:18m:24s
Total Downtime: 12d 13h:44m:59s
Total Reboots: 14
Mean Time Between Reboots: 2.06 days
Total Bluescreens: 0
```

A second method is to get the hard drive "on" time, using some disk verification software that can also report the power used by the hard drive, from which we can estimate the CPU usage... not so direct.

**Q3 method to check the CPU processor or GPU graphic card failure errors due to overheating or over-usage**

**FINDINGS**

I find several tools to detect CPU processor  Usage process reports like   `Perform.exe`, process  monitor, Wmi, procdump, process lasso, process explorer, Process monitor, taskinfo, hwinfo...

As office machines can be used by novice operators overnight, and some of them kept the machines switched on overtime, I have to check when it happens.

We may put temperature monitors and logs in future (maybe based on `hwinfo`), but for the past days  without those, is there any way to get the logs reports of CPU gpu failures?

I find that the CPU /GPU overheat overuse problem is displayed in the bios post startup or on some Windows shutdown event  log...  and the windows shutdown is saved in  Windows events, with event id number 6008 and with event Id number 41d. **Is there any tool software to count and  filter event Ids from  windows event log?**

I also finded the **Bios event logs** options are there in some board, but I don't know if  overheating or overclocking info is recorded there. But UEFI bios do have. Event log option but  **Is there any tools softwares to retrieve BIOS  event errors logs.**

So it remains to collect the information from the BIOS and the Windows event about the history of overheating (caused by overuse) or the blue screen errors that have occurred in the past... is there any place where windows7,10 saves this information and any command tool to recover those reports?

Comment: Welcome on SuperUser. Good effort to [edit] your question. Try to be a little more essential. As in the past they said __often the good is in the middle__ `;-)`. I edited your question for what I understood. Feel you free to rollback and please finish the last part, if it is essential (and cut  whatever it is not needed). By the way, remember this is not the site to directly request software recommendations, although the answers may be "software". And you should ask only one question for each post...

Comment: Note that if you have a bunch of programs that outputs what you need, you can always create a script (cmd.exe, power shell, or even bash shell - Windows subsystem for Linux - WSL) in which you can write the commands one after the other (each on a new line) and see on the screen or redirect (`>>myoutput.log`) in a text file their output.